# Regex lookahead and lookbehind assertions

Tags: regex

I'm used to the standard usage of lookahead and lookbehind assertions like so
(for e.g.): `.(?=foo)` and `(?<=foo).`. That is in lookahead case we need to place the search token before the lookahead, in case of lookbehind we need to place the search token after the lookbehind. But i've also seen such a construct: `(?=foo).` .Does that make sense and if so what will it match?

Answer (score 1):

#### I've also seen `(?=foo).`. Does that make sense and if so what will it match?

It's still a positive lookahead regexp:

> [image]

Source [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Notes:

- If your test expression is `afoo` it will match `f`.
- To match `foo` use `(?=foo).+`

Comment: Ok but can You explain me how does such regex work? For e.g. having `afoo` test string how does the regex process the test string letters trying a match?

Comment: @Ringger81 It matches a single character from the rexexp (that's what `.` means). See updated answer.